# Session variable + WebMethod variable value not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I have a web app with a dropdown list. When a new index is selected I have to storing the value to a session variable, which is created on Session_Start event.

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Add("testValue", "test");
}
```

On selectedindex changed event i'm setting the new value like this

```
Session["testValue"] = DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

I have a web service where I retrieve the value of the session variable like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string getValue()
{

    var testVal = Session["testValue"].ToString();

    return testVal.ToString();
}
```

From a console app I connect to the web service and retrieve the value returned by `getValue()`, however the initial value is always being returned. any idea please?

Comment: check whether the values of the items in your dropdownlist are different

Comment: You say `from a console app` - are you expecting your console app and webbrowser to share the same session ?

Comment: Hi Richard, my intention is to have the webMethod retrieve the session variable value, which currently is doing when i access the webservice.asmx and invoke the method the value is returned accordingly. Shouldnt it be the same behaviour when the url is accessed from the console app?

Comment: Remember to enable session in web.config
    <sessionState mode="InProc"/>

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because when the console app is run it seems that a new session is created. Using Application state using Application.Set and Application.Get solved the issue. Hopefully i will not have issues when the system will be used by multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Here the values are not changed, You didn't change the values. So nothing expected

```
public string getValue()
{
    var testVal = Session["testValue"].ToString();
    return testVal.ToString();
}
```

The mistake is probably in dropdownlist

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Session["testValue] = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.text;
}
}
```

And,

```
protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Session["testvalue"] = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.text;
}
```

Also try with

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["testvalue"]
```

in both parts

Comment: that method should not change the value of the session variable but retrieve it. the value of session variable is changed on SelectedIndexChanged event of DropDown

Comment: the session variable value is changed accordingly since when i access the webservice through its url and invoke the method it returns the value chosen by the client. the issue when accessing the webmethod from a console application.

Comment: Try with static method. +1

Comment: if you mean the webmethod as static, then the webmethod would not be available when consuming the webservice from the console app.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the values of the items in your dropdown list are different.This is essential for your selected index changed event to be fired.